# Можно ли при запросе на основании данных двух таблиц, преобразовывать данные в записях сформированного запроса?

Tags: ms-access

Есть две таблицы, оператор заполняя некую форму формирует одну из таблиц полностью(в примере "Заполняемая таблица 2"), так же он заполняет и вторую таблицу (в примере "Заполняемая таблица 1"). Но вторая таблица, так же может пополнятся и из других источников. Задача при формировании запроса из этих двух таблиц. В поле "Версия"(в примере Версия "ДатаТаб1") выводить самую свежую версию, а в поле "Дата" выводить только даты "посещения" (в примере это поле "ДатаТаб2"), но если дата из таблицы 1(то есть в поле "ДатаТаб1"), больше чем дата в таблицы 2 (в поле "ДатаТаб2"), то ставить какую не будь отметку в сформированном отчете, к примеру звездочку (*) после этой даты или версии, как бы символизируя, что версию обновили уже после посещения... То есть другими словами, можно ли при запроси на основании данных двух таблиц, преобразовывать данные в записях сформированного запроса?

[Пример БД](https://yadi.sk/d/FulKbt78vPkycg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *можно ли при запроси на основании данных двух таблиц, преобразовывать данные в записях сформированного запроса?* Решение именно этой задачи требует изменения текста запроса - поэтому вопрос лишён смысла. А что до подразумеваемой задачи... вычисляемые поля в запросах - обычное дело.

Comment: В смысле с помощью  IIf ?

Comment: Да, именно. В подзапросе получить макс. время для каждой задачи, и сравнить с временем из второй таблицы, в зависимости от результата вывести ту или иную пометку.

Comment: Дело в то, что я не умею склеивать поля в запросе, ведь мне нужна и сама дата из второй таблицы и отметка рядом с ней (отметка на основании разности дат из двух таблиц).
По этому я реализовал объединение "криво", через отчеты:
https://yadi.sk/d/ehMIYMMHXwD_TQ

Comment: *я не умею склеивать поля в запросе* А чё там сложного? `IIF( table1.field1 > table2.field2 ; 'text 1' ; 'text 2' )`...

Comment: да не, в моем случае надо примерно вот так:
      'IIf(t2.ДатаТаб2<t1.mx,t2.ДатаТаб2 + "*","")'

Comment: Строковые данные не складывают - эта операция для чисел. Слияние строк - это конкатенация, и для неё используется не плюс `+`, а амперсанд `&`.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, получилось:) 
SELECT t2.*, IIf(t2.ДатаТаб2<t1.mx,t2.ДатаТаб2 & "*","") AS Обновление
Но только вариант с формой более удобен на мой взгляд, так как там можно реализовать в виде сноски, А в запросе наверное нельзя:(

Comment: Судя по всему в отчете пометку указать как сноски, технической возможности нет:(